# How could you build a universe

Tags: physics, astronomy

EDIT : I made significant changes to the question which is by its nature open.

Dark energy and its repulsive energy that expanded space at its origin was decisive in creating the playground for the laws of nature and particles by menas of cooling and keep expanding at certain rates.

Mastering Dark energy has the power to shape the size of space and thus what it does with (imagine space would have been keept at a minuscule size or expand at infinite speed, the particles and associated laws would have been different).

Dark Energy does not interact with matter and increases and decreases the expansion of space (exerting negative pressure expanding the elastic fabric of space). Its energy remains constant (does not weaken) with the expansion of space and is not associated with regular matter as per its dynamics so it may be a property of space (vacum energy) or maybe independent of it and exert a force on it as so far Dark energy only intereacts with Space via its changes in acceleration. My guess is that is a non constant property of space and maybe related to the vacum of space and its energy content (E=M) However there is a large discrepancy "vacumm catastophy" where vacuum energy in a cubic meter of free space has been estimated to be 10−9 joules (10-2 ergs).However, in both Quantum Electrodynamics (QED) and Stochastic Electrodynamics (SED), consistency with the principle of Lorentz covariance and with the magnitude of the Planck constant requires it to have a much larger value of 10^113 joules per cubic meter. A monstruous amount of energy (Total energy of the universe is estimated to be 4×10^69 Jules).

Previously of space and time which must also been created at one point there must have been energy potential or virtual and as result of something must have becomed real. My believe is that dark energy has some sort of flavour of being a relic force from the pre-universe era (no time then) from that era of energy potential in the way it intereacts with space (same amount per cubic meter regardless of expansion however seems to be constant as per unit of new space and time created as per expansion) However we dont know if it was always like this possibly not as through its effects we can see by changes in acceleration or are that variations in the expansion are due to changes in the constant of time at a plank scale at a universal scale what we perceive as inflation, expansion and now acceleration.

I am trying to understand how to create a universe as to develop worldbuilding capabilities from a scientific point of view although I understand that is highly speculative science.

Therefore the question is if there could be an external force to our space and time influencing or modifying our space and time? and what force could that be and what possible mechanisms of transmision to our universe will it have to use as to affect time and space.

Comment: I'd honestly have to say this is a prime candidate to move to Physics...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about physics.

Comment: It's also unclear and borderline speculative.

Comment: Floating point error?

Comment: I'm going to give an answer, but this is ABSOLUTELY a Physics problem, not a world building problem

Comment: I think it's a little misleading to say that it is off-topic because it is about physics.  We have over sixty questions in the physics tag.  Physics is within our purview.  The problem is that this is all about the real world and has nothing to do with creating a fictional world.

Comment: This is actually too speculative for physics. It could use rewording, though. Something along the lines of "How should I explain dark energy in my setting" with some specifics of setting explained. (Otherwise it would be too open here too, I think.)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Is it answerable ?

Comment: I believe that with a bit of trimming, this one is a serious candidate for WB. After all, it's **literally** asking how to build a universe. But seriously do edit it though.

Comment: I think the OP is suggesting that there is a god-like being(s) somewhere that is creating, or at least manipulating, reality and that maybe dark energy/ dark matter are the tools being used to do said creation/manipulation. OP wants to know how that is happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dark energy and dark matter are concepts in modern astrophysics that confuse many people, because they exist but they don't exist.

We have models of the cosmos.  They work pretty darn well most of the time.  However, lately we've been doing observations and we've seen some of the numbers don't add up.  The model is failing.

Someone noticed that the discrepancies can be resolved with the addition of "dark energy" and "dark matter" which do not interact with the rest of the universe in the normal way energy and matter do.

This does not mean we have "discovered" dark matter or dark energy.  Rather, they are ways we are accounting for things we do not understand about our universe.  Eventually we will discover a new model which does a better job of explaining these issues, and can address the sorts of questions you are asking.  Until then, they're just big fudge factors that let us continue using our models.  If we didn't do *something* like that, we'd just throw up our hands and astrophysics would go on a vacation until someone figured it out.  Science doesn't stop like that -- we fudge things!

As an analogy, consider "centrifugal force," a *fictitious force* that pulls you to the outer rim of a rotating body.  It's called a fictitious force because it's actually not a force, but an artifact of the rotating frame called "centripetal acceleration."

Now, consider if you didn't have this understanding of rotating frames.  They are complicated after all.  Consider a young student who has only ever worked in Inertial frames (i.e. non-rotating frames).  This young student gets on a Gravitron, the carnival ride which spins about its axis and pins you against the outside walls, with so much force that it can even lift you up along the angled outer wall against gravity!

If this student had to make sense of what happened to them in the Gravitron, they would see that what happened to them can be modeled by a "center fleeing force," but they wouldn't be able to explain what causes this center fleeing force, or why it vanishes when the rotation stops.  After all, they aren't touching the central axis. There has to be some force emitting out from that center pressing them down.

They would have to admit that this model is flawed.  Forces just don't work that way, and the young student knows it.  However, this isn't going to stop the student from getting on the Gravitron again and enjoying it.  Maybe they'd even spin upside down (which is insane, unless you're willing to trust this "center fleeing force" to pin you to the walls and keep you from falling down).

Eventually, they will discover rotating frames and be able to model "center seeking acceleration," which has the same effect as the "center fleeing force," but has the advantage of having a rational explanation instead of a shrugging of shoulders.  At this point, they might even start calling their old "center fleeing force" a "fictitious force," to make it clear that there is no force, but that others who don't understand rotating frames can think of it as a source.

At this time, their model will be complete enough to explain another effect: the Coriolis effect.  Objects with velocities act *really weird* in rotating frames due to the Coriolis effect.  If the young student had to explain the Coriolis effect without understanding rotating frames, they'd be at a loss.  Even when you *do* understand them, the effect still feels a bit magical.

Astrophysics is trying to learn their equivalent of rotating frames.  When they do, these undesirable funny effects will be explained in much simpler terms (but on a much more complicated model).